# Stuck on SQL Server procedure code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error from this code

```
DECLARE @existingEmail AS INT

SET NOCOUNT ON;

@existingEmail = COUNT(*) AS total FROM table WHERE email = @email;

INSERT INTO table2 (email)
VALUES (CASE WHEN @existingEmail IS 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END);
```

That is the error I am getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_counts, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@existingEmail'.

Comment: Do you really want to `insert` a new row or `update` an existing row?

Comment: `@existingEmail = COUNT(*) AS total FROM table WHERE email = @email;` Where's the word `SELECT`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `COUNT` to check existence may not be best idea from performance point of view:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (email)
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE email = @email) THEN 'Yes' 
       ELSE 'No' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
@existingEmail = COUNT(*) as total from table where email = @email;
```

You need to do this:

```
SELECT @existingEmail = COUNT(*) as total from table where email = @email;
```

or this:

```
SET @existingEmail = (SELECT COUNT(*) as total from table where email = @email);
```

Comment: after using set or select, I am still getting an error: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_counts, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_counts, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '1'.`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong near the `FROM` in the code you posted, so probably you obfuscated it.  As for the `1` you should be using `= 1` instead of `IS 1`.

Answer (score 0):

On the line where you are trying to set your variable `@existingEmail` you are missing the key word `set`. if you update that line to the following this should resolve that error.

```
set @existingEmail = (SELECT COUNT(*) from table where email = @email);
```

Comment: this would be a much better answer if you could elaborate on why you proposed this as the solution and what it is doing. not a just code answer

Comment: I felt there was no need to elaborate,since the other comments covered the "why" of it.